# Update Jinja element after rendering template in flask

Tags: python, templates, flask, jinja2, bokeh

After rendering a template in a flask function, can the elements be changed dynamically i.e. without re-rendering the template?

Say I have this flask page:

```
@app.route("/"):
def index():
  ### generate div content
  ### have a button callback that changes the div content
  return render_template('index.html', divcontent=content)
```

And then in the template:

```
{{divcontent}}
```

Even though the callback successfully changes the div content variable in flask, the page is not updated. Am I correct to say that this is because the page has been rendered when the page first loaded and thus the content is not dynamically updated?

In context; I'm embedding the div component of a bokeh plot in a template like so:

```
script, div = components(fig, INLINE)
return render_template('index.html', script=script, div=div)
```

but I also have a dropdown menu on the same page which if changed, should change the plot and so in the dropdown callback I'm 'regenerating' the script and div by recalling the components function with the now new 'fig', but the page does not show these changes and I presume this is because the page was rendered the first time and so the new arguments script and div are not being updated.

I'm also doing something similar with multiple dropdowns; i.e. when one dropdown is selected in bokeh widget, it calls a callback which is supposed to populate another dropdown with custom list. The following is the actual callback JS code:

```
dropdown2 = Select(title="Parameter:", value="Select parameter", options=['Select parameter'])

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(dropdown2=dropdown2), code="""
    var selValue = cb_obj.get('value');
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "retrieveColumns",
    data:'id='+selValue,
    success: function(data){
        dropdown2.set('options',data.List);
    }
    });
    column_select.set('options','hi');
    column_select.trigger('change');
""")

dropdown1 = Select(title="Choose type:", value="Select type", options=selectList, callback=callback)
```

This is a similar question to part of [this](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/bokeh/qknEaRqH_Cs) question, where the OP asked how to send back slider values to jinja. Javascript callback is one of the 'solution' however like I said above, I'm unable to 'update' the jinja elements.